# Syntax for adding a closure to a function?

Tags: swift, closures

I'm  trying to create a function that has a closure. Nothing is passed to the function, just after it finishes another function has to be called.  Something like this:

```
  func addGradient(closure: syntax) {
(closure: _ in ("function call here")   )}
```

so it can be called similiar to this

`addGradient(closure: "function to be called"`)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the signature for the function minus any of the names:

```
func doIt(one: Int, two: String) -> [String] {
  …
}
```

Would have the closure signature of:

```
(Int, String) -> [String]
```

So yours would be:

```
func addGradient(closure: (Int, String) -> [String]) {
  …
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
addGradient(closure: doIt)
```

One more note, a function like this:

```
func doAgain() {
  …
}
```

Has a closure signature of this:

```
() -> ()
```